# Replace NULL in querystring asp.net

Tags: asp.net, replace

I have a `Response.Redirect` on a buttonclick with two querystring-parameters that hold the value from two textboxes. If I leave the textboxes empty I get this URL: `/Order.aspx?LastName=&FirstName=`. I want to replace the NULL value with "%20" like this `/Order.aspx?LastName=%20&FirstName=%20`.

Please help my with the if-statements to changes this, I'm really new to this. Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSearchFirstLastName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx?LastName=" + SearchLastName.Text.Trim() + "&FirstName=" + SearchFirstName.Text.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check string using [string.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx), if true then set something of your choice like `" "` or `string.Empty`.

```
protected void btnSearchFirstLastName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx?LastName=" 
    + string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLastName.Text) ? " ": SearchLastName.Text.Trim() 
    + "&FirstName=" + string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchFirstName.Text) ? " " : SearchFirstName.Text.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void btnSearchFirstLastName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstName = "%20";
    string lastName = "%20";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(SearchFirstName.Text)
        firstName = SearchFirstName.Text.Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(SearchLastName.Text)
        lastName = SearchLastName.Text.Trim();

    Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx?LastName=" + lastName + "&FirstName=" + firstName);
}
```

Comment: No probs, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply add this condition that if textbox is empty, then text should be as mentioned by you.
Like:

```
If(abc.text!=string.empty || abc.text!=null)
{
param value=abc.text;
}
else
param value="%20";
```

Note: This is a side option, you can opt if coding paradigms is not a concern here.